# How to get a value in parentheses?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

z=`echo "$a*(1+($p/(100*$g)))^((($j)+($m/12)+($t/365))*$g)" | wcalc -EE`
y=`echo read$z/$k^2 | wcalc`
echo $y
```

My second line does a calulation `$z/($k^2)`  but I need `($z/$k)^2` how do I do that?

Comment: Um... maybe `echo "($z/$k)^2" | wcalc`? Not sure what that extra `read` thing is there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as I understand it, is that `z` is not a number but something of the form `= 1.2345` (that is to say, a string with a `=` before the number). I think the sanest way to make this work is to make `z` a number. Unfortunately, `wcalc` does not seem to have an option for this, so I'd resort to using `awk`:

```
#                                                  here, at the end ------v
z=`echo "$a*(1+($p/(100*$g)))^((($j)+($m/12)+($t/365))*$g)" | wcalc -EE | awk '{ print $2 }'`
y=`echo "read = ($z/$k)^2" | wcalc` # and perhaps apply a similar transformation here.
echo "$y"
```

Take note that `wcalc` will not remember the assignment to `read`, though, because the process immediately ends. I don't know what you want to achieve with that.

Comment: How is `1.2345` not a number?

Comment: There's `=` before it in `wcalc`'s output. `read$z/$k^2` expands to something like `read = 1/2^2`. I edited the answer for clarity.